# ElasticSearch index score

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, configuration, yaml

I noticed that the more objects are in the table, the greater the relevance when searching by keywords. So for example there are 2 entities, services and news, the services have the head "tick removal", the news has the heading "hand removal", I have a total of 1000 services and 50 news, and if I search for the word “removal” then the relevance of the service is 1200 and the news of 200 , how can I set up ElasticSearchBundle so that the number of elements does not play a role during intexation?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you do not want to take into consideration the relevancy calculation and that you probably want to disable `tf-idf` all together.

TF-IDF takes into consideration the count of occurrences of the words.

Take a look at [Constant Score Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html) which might be what you are looking for and that you can make use of [Filter Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) in order to not take into consideration the relevancy calculation

Below is how your query could be constructed using them both:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{ 
   "query":{ 
      "constant_score":{ 
         "filter":{ 
            "query_string":{ 
               "query":"removal"
            }
         },
         "boost":1.2
      }
   }
}
```

Note that when you execute the above query, all the documents would have a constant score of **1.2**

Note that if you are not bothered for score at all, best to use simple **Filter Queries** where it would simply act as boolean query.

This [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html) mentions that:

> Filter queries do not calculate relevance scores. To speed up
>   performance, Elasticsearch automatically caches frequently used filter
>   queries.

See you also have added advantage of performance here.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: hey @Artem, was the above answer useful. Is there anything else you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try "boolean similarity" instead of tf/idf, there is a nice article about it here: https://saskia-vola.com/when-simple-is-better-the-boolean-similarity-module

The scoring function for the boolean model is much simpler than tf/idf. Either a term appears in a document or not. So you have 2 possible scores: 1 and 0 for every term. If three of your terms appear in a document, this document will have a score 3, that is much simpler to work within some cases.

You can implement it just by adding `"similarity": "boolean"` to your text fields:

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc" : {
      "properties" : {
        "content" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "similarity" : "boolean"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```